# How can I add/set the referer header in Angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient

How to set the header in httpclient Angular 8+, I have trying using interceptor and add the header but it is not working.

```
const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Referer', 'abc')
});
```

Comment: this header is a browser default header, it shouldn't be and cannot be changed

Comment: Just in javascript? Because in .net it is posible.

Comment: did you ever run .net in the browser with this possibility? browser  is doing a lot of built in security things for the safety of the client. you just cannot violate those security things, because that would be a breach in browser APIs. in this case you are trying to trick 3rd party API by changing the referer header, so this api would think you are not the one that you really are

Comment: btw it is possible in nodejs as well, becase it is not browser and it is being run on the server